# Civimail produces saving error when sending test

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM 4.6.8

I was editing an email when the "Send test" button triggered the message...

```
Error: Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved
```

Unable to replicate in demo site since there's no outgoing email (saving the email doesn't actually produce the error, despite the error's wording).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went in and submitted a test mailing that I wasn't able to preview. This caused the cronjob to spit out the error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mb_strtoupper() in <b>/home/ourbase/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php</b> on line <b>703</b><br />
```

The key there is the function mb_strtoupper() [that's "string to upper"]. To fix this, you need to enable "mbstring" on your php/apache build. In my case, this was done through the WHM interface as follows:

1. Go to EasyApache
2. Customize the current profile
3. On Step 3 (?) click on "Exhaustive Options"
4. Check the checkbox for MBString
5. Build & Compile (takes a while), and wait until it's done.

If you don't have access to that solution, consider one of these lesser temporary solutions while you wait for someone to resolve it:
1. Remove all `<strong>` and/or `<b>` tags or...
2. Manually put text in the plain text box

Answer (score 1):

I received this message because my Firewall (CSF) was improperly configured to block the outgoing mail port. When I resolved that, the error disappeared.